# Using the "%d" + constant in the printf function

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
 int c = 1;
 printf("%d" + 0 , c);
 printf("%d" + 1 , c);
 printf("%d" + 2 , c);
 printf("%d" + 3 , c);
}
```

The output of the following program is:

1d

Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Look into string literals and pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when coding `"literalstring" + 3` you get the 4<sup>th</sup> (since 4 = 3+1 and arrays index start at 0) and following bytes of the `"literalstring"` (which is terminated by a zero-byte) so you get `"eralstring"`, hence

- `"%d" + 0` is `"%d"`
- `"%d" + 1` is `"d"`, notice that `printf("d", 1)` *ignores* the argument 1!
- `"%d" + 2` is `""`  an empty string
- `"%d" + 3` points to an undefined location and dereferencing it (like `printf` probably does) is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) ...

Comment: And `"%d" + 3` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I would say that dereferencing `"%d" + 3` is an undefined behavior

Comment: Right, I assumed `printf` de-references.

Answer (score 2):

For this below one you will get the output as

```
printf("%d\n" + 0 , c);  -> 1 // +0 so Value of c will came
printf("%d\n" + 1 ,c);   -> d // +1 "d" will print.
printf("%da\n" + 2 , c); -> a // +2 second character "a" will print
printf("%dab\n" + 3 , c);-> b // +3 third character "b" will print
```

So it is getting the characters from the given string.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d" + 0 , c);
```

is the same as

```
printf("%d", c);
```

Which prints the value of `c`,i.e, 1.

```
printf("%d" + 1 , c)
```

is the same as

```
printf("d", c)
```

which prints "d" on the screen. The lthird `printf` is similar to

```
printf("", c)
```

which prints nothing and the last one invokes UB(Undefined Bahaviour)

Answer (score 1):

You are moving the pointer to `"%d"` that is passed to `printf` so

1. `printf("%d" + 0, c)`

   ```
   printf("%d", c); 
   /* prints the value of c */
   ```
2. `printf("%d" + 1, c)`

   ```
   printf("d", c); 
   /* prints 'd' */
   ```
3. `printf("%d" + 2, c)`

   ```
   printf("", c);
   /* the format string is empty nothing printed */
   ```
4. `printf("%d" + 3, c)` Here printf will get an address that points past the buffer, that's **undefined behavior**.

And finally

```
1d
```

is printed.

It is possible that at `printf("%d" + 3, c)` a segmention fault signal is recieved by your program, the `1d` will still be printed if the `stdout` is flushed before the segmentation fault.